# Decode Firebase token in Java

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am trying to verify/decode a token on my backend and then retrieve the users UID from the decoded token. The token is generated by the client as a string. The backend successfully retrieves/sets data to Firebase which leads me to believe that Firebase is initializing correctly so that wouldn't be the issue. However when run, there seems to be an error that causes a crash.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException, FirebaseAuthException {
        File credentialsFile = getFile();

        FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(credentialsFile);

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("***")
                .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

        String idToken = "***";

        //LINE 43 IS BELOW
        FirebaseToken decodedToken = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(idToken);
        String uid = decodedToken.getUid();

        System.out.println("UID: " + uid);
    }
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:108)
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:37)
    at com.google.api.client.json.webtoken.JsonWebSignature$Parser.parse(JsonWebSignature.java:599)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseToken.parse(FirebaseToken.java:44)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$4.execute(FirebaseAuth.java:484)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$4.execute(FirebaseAuth.java:477)
    at com.google.firebase.internal.CallableOperation.call(CallableOperation.java:36)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.verifyIdToken(FirebaseAuth.java:441)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.verifyIdToken(FirebaseAuth.java:415)
    at App.main(App.java:43)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: Can you log the `idToken` just before calling verify and see it indeed has a valid JWT?

Comment: I have logged the idToken from the client and then just copied it as a string to the backend for testing. When logged, the idToken is the same token that is generated from the client - 
 (dBEpToFukRw:APA91bFeSmEukr6D-AB1_ip92zxBpCx7JuLTwjNuCoj9MqvwBfQupDoxTudM8aurDn8IpgRu1S55toV3T71MIT2f13pJl4m4U8pfQa6IC367cJ3Qax3ub0TovUMITw3H-BDBelZzm-Lw)

Comment: That is not a valid ID token/JWT. A JWT has three parts separated by dots. This has two parts separated by `:`.

Comment: Problem solved, you are right! Issue was with the way the token was being generated from client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Issue was with the way the token was being generated from the client as pointed out by [hiranya-jayathilaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5190886/hiranya-jayathilaka). This is how i was generating the token:

```
String idToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

This is how it should be generated according to [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens):

```
FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            mUser.getIdToken(true)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                String idToken = task.getResult().getToken();
                                // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
                                // ...
                            } else {
                                // Handle error -> task.getException();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```